# Paginaçao JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Estava brincando com JavaFX e travei quando quis adicionar paginação a minha pequena aplicação.

Tenho uma `listview` preenchida (como pode ser visto na imagem), quando clico em um item, suas informações são mostradas a direita.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como a aplicação foi modelada usando FXML, coloquei o componente `pagination` na tela, porém este não apresenta nenhuma ação até esse momento. Justamente isso que gostaria de acrescentar.

Quando clicar nas setas ou números do `pagination`, queria que o item correspondente fosse selecionado e consequentemente suas informações mostradas. Como fazer isso?

Como pedido, eis o código de minha classe de controle:
Ps.: o código completo pode ser encontrado em https://github.com/marcelcunha/AgendaTest

```
public class ViewController implements Initializable {

Set<Pessoa> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();

@FXML
private TextField nomeTF;
@FXML
private TextField sobrenomeTF;
@FXML
private TextField celularTF;
@FXML
private TextField telTF;
@FXML
private ListView<Pessoa> pessoasLV;
@FXML
private Pagination pagination;


ObservableList<Pessoa> oList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    nomeTF.setEditable(false);
    sobrenomeTF.setEditable(false);
    celularTF.setEditable(false);
    telTF.setEditable(false);

    populaLista();

    pessoasLV.setCellFactory(preencheLista());

    pessoasLV.getSelectionModel().
            selectedItemProperty().addListener(selecionaLista());
    pessoasLV.setItems(oList);
    pagination.setPageCount(oList.size());
}


Callback<ListView<Pessoa>, ListCell<Pessoa>> preencheLista() {
    return new Callback<ListView<Pessoa>, ListCell<Pessoa>>() {

        @Override
        public ListCell<Pessoa> call(ListView<Pessoa> param) {
            return new ListCell<Pessoa>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Pessoa item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!empty && item != null) {
                        setText(item.getNome() + " " + item.getSobrenome());
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
}

ChangeListener<Pessoa> selecionaLista() {
    return new ChangeListener<Pessoa>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Pessoa> observable, Pessoa oldValue, Pessoa newValue) {
            nomeTF.setText(newValue.getNome());
            sobrenomeTF.setText(newValue.getSobrenome());
            celularTF.setText(Arrays.toString(newValue.getCelular()));
            telTF.setText(Arrays.toString(newValue.getTelefoneRes()));
        }
    };
}
public void populaLista() {
    set.add(new Pessoa("Maria", "Silva", "Rua A", 2, " "));
    set.add(new Pessoa("Joana", "Carvalho", "Rua Paraíba", 452, "A "));
    set.add(new Pessoa("sergio", "Pereira", "Av 2", 143, " "));

    oList.addAll(set);

}
```

}

Comment: Fica de recomendação então para essa e até para futuras perguntas, sempre poste o código relevante a dúvida/problema junto com a pergunta, no formato de um **[mcve]**.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta conforme solicitado. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O pagination precisa de páginas criadas pelo pageFactory para funcionar corretamente. Para isso você utiliza a função .setPageFactory(), conforme mostrado abaixo:

```
pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
       public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {
           // Crie um nó aqui
       }
   });
```

Basicamente esse Callback será executado ao clicar no número da página (pageIndex), retornando o Node correspondente.

Normalmente a paginação é usada para navegar através de múltiplas páginas(Nodes) em que um único conteúdo foi dividido em partes menores. Talvez não seja ideal para passar item por item. Espero que ainda ajude!

Mais informações na documentação do [Pagination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html).

Exemplos de utilização: [Using JavaFX UI Controls: 25 Pagination Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/pagination.htm).